# If C/C++ are native languages, then how can they be used on Macs?

Tags: c++, c, native-code

I thought that native code was code that was designed to run on a specific machine. So what confuses me is how can C/C++ be run on other platforms and machines? The only thing I can come up with is that they would need a whole different compiler that would compile the code into the code that was specific to the machine.. I am just confused when C/C++ are referred to as native languages.

Comment: " The only thing I can come up with is that they would need a whole different compiler that would compile the code into the code that was specific to the machine" - Bingo!

Comment: Duh.  Yes, you need a compiler targeted to the processor instruction set, and, to a lesser degree, targeted to the OS process model.

Comment: (Remember, "Mac" encompasses several different and incompatible processor models.)

Comment: If you have a compiler that changes C to x86 machine code, with a lot of work you could change the compiler to generate machine code for some other machine.  This is called retargeting a compiler.  The gcc compiler has taken this to an extreme since it has multiple front ends for different languages (C, C++, Java, Fortran, ...) and multiple backends for different machines (x86, ARM, SPARC, MIPS, ...).

Answer (score 9):

> The only thing I can come up with is that they would need a whole different compiler that would compile the code into the code that was specific to the machine

You've answered your own question! The compiler is the piece that generates machine code that the target platform understands and executes.

When people say "native language" they usually mean that the language is translated (compiled) into machine code rather than some intermediate form (e.g., byte code for Java) or executed by an interpreter (e.g., Perl).

Comment: So for java you can pretty much have the same compiler for all platforms since the bytecode is going to be run in the JVM and if the JVM is made for that platform then voila. Is that right?

Comment: With Java there is no native compiler, only the bit that translates Java into bytecode. The JVM is written in a native language and is compiled for the target platform. So you can run any Java program on any platform as long as there exists a JVM for that platform. The Java code itself is platform independent because it is executed by the JVM, which is where the platform-specific stuff lives.

Comment: Even with Java you still need a different JVM for each different platform. You can't escape from the fact that at some point the underlying executing code is different for each architecture.